# i want to change the font style of the text by clicking the button in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
const textBold =()=>{
  const bold_text=document.getElementsByClassName('.form-control');
  bold_text.style.fontStyle = "italic";
  setText(bold_text)
}
```

On clicking the button it takes me to a blank page on the browser.

Comment: What's the code of the button?

Comment: Hey welcome to stack overflow. Please could you post the code for the entire react component you have? It will help with understanding what's happening

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `getElementsByClassName` method, it will return an array/collection of elements containing the given classes.

If you have single element, then use `.querySelector` instead.

Or if you prefer to use `getElementsByClassName` method, then find out the element that you needed by using for loop or `.find()` method and apply the styles.

In React, I think using `ref` s is better than using DOM APIs to target an element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're almost there as you're using state, but you shouldn't be mixing native DOM operations and React - React has its own method of updating the DOM which will conflict with traditional DOM update methods; for instance: using `getElementsByClassName` to update elements' styles.

So, we have a method that is called when the button is clicked which updates the state, and a joined array of class names that changes depending on the state. If the state is `true` then the "italic" class is added. That class string can then be used on your elements.

Here the style is only applied to inputs 1 & 3.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ italic, setItalic ] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setItalic(true);
  }

  const controlStyle = [
    'form-control',
    italic && 'italic'
  ].join(' ');

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        className={controlStyle}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        className={controlStyle}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.form-control { color: red; }
.italic { font-style: italic; color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```